# XMLHttpRequest on click clean the response before making another request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a XMLHttpRequest request that give me back, via API, a shipping cost.

I active the request on button click. When I ask for another quote the response the is print is the same of the first request, but in the console I can see the different data.

Why can't I see the correct response? 
How can I always print only the updated request?

$( "#checkers" ).click(function() {

```
var myKey = "xxxxx";
var name = $('#Inputfield_pad_firstname').val();
var company = $('#Inputfield_company_name').val();
var street1 = $('#Inputfield_pad_address').val();


var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 1) {
        $('#wrap_Inputfield_shipping_choose').css("opacity",".4");
        $('#Inputfield_shipping_choose_1').nextAll().remove();
        $('#Inputfield_shipping_choose_2').nextAll().remove();
    }
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        console.log( this.response );
        $('#wrap_Inputfield_shipping_choose').css("opacity","1");
        $('#Inputfield_shipping_choose_1').after("<p>JS<b><?= $rate['Rates'][0]['carrier_label'] ?></b> costo: <?= $rate['Rates'][0]['rate'] ?> Tempo<?= $rate['Rates'][0]['delivery_days'] ?></p>");
        $('#Inputfield_shipping_choose_2').after("<p>JS<b><?= $rate['Rates'][1]['carrier_label'] ?></b> costo: <?= $rate['Rates'][1]['rate'] ?> Tempo<?= $rate['Rates'][1]['delivery_days'] ?></p>");
    }
};
xhttp.responseType = 'json';
xhttp.open("POST", 'https://www.xxxxx.it/form/getRates.php', true);
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({
            'Method' : 'GetRates',
            'Params' : {
            .... data ...
        }
    })
);
```

PHP part:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$raw = file_get_contents('php://input');

$connection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.xxxx.com/api');
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: xxxxx",
    "password:"
));
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $raw );
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
echo curl_exec($connection);
curl_close($connection);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct answer:

```
$('#Inputfield_shipping_choose_1').after("<p><b>" +this.response.Rates[0].carrier_label+ "</b> costo: "+ this.response.Rates[0].rate+" Tempo "+ this.response.Rates[0].delivery_days+"</p>");
```

the error was an encorect syntax.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you didn't update ui with the data you retrieved through api.

I assume these 2 lines are suppose to do the update, right?

```js
$('#Inputfield_shipping_choose_1').after("<p>JS<b><?= $rate['Rates'][0]['carrier_label'] ?></b> costo: <?= $rate['Rates'][0]['rate'] ?> Tempo<?= $rate['Rates'][0]['delivery_days'] ?></p>");
$('#Inputfield_shipping_choose_2').after("<p>JS<b><?= $rate['Rates'][1]['carrier_label'] ?></b> costo: <?= $rate['Rates'][1]['rate'] ?> Tempo<?= $rate['Rates'][1]['delivery_days'] ?></p>");
```

you should update them with the data from `this.response` rather than `<?= ... ?>`.

Comment: Yes this two line print the API response, the problem that the data inside aren't update with the second call. How I can update these?

Comment: the reason it's not updated is because the data inside `<?= ... ?>` will not change unless you refresh the page. You want to update them with the data you get from api which should be `this.response`

Comment: I can't refresh the page because the data in the input aren't save. I have to refresh only the `this.response`

Comment: what I mean is change `...<p>JS<b><?= $rate['Rates'][0]['carrier_label'] ?>...` to something like `...<p>JS<b>this.response.rate['Rates'][0]['carrier_label']...`

Comment: yes man, it was what I was trying to do, I don't really know the syntax with which to call the data.

Comment: This: `" +this.response.Rates[0].carrier_label+ "`. If upload your answer I will give you the correct answer.

Comment: well... I'm not sure what's the problem now. does this not work? `" +this.response.Rates[0].carrier_label+ "`

Comment: yes. works so well. 
`$('#Inputfield_shipping_choose_1').after("<p><b>" +this.response.Rates[0].carrier_label+ "</b> costo: "+ this.response.Rates[0].rate+" Tempo "+ this.response.Rates[0].delivery_days+"</p>");`